# populated javascript array with zero length

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, polymerfire

I have an array that is for unacessable by index like this: `myArr[index]`.
after logging my array in Dev tools i get the following output that looks like an empty array

[image: my array looks like this]

however after expanding the array i get the following:

[image: expanded array]

which is a populated array but with 0 length

is there an explanation for this and how can i be able to access the items in the array?

i'm using a vadeen grid to display a set of data in a polymer app

```
      <vaadin-grid selection-mode="multi" items="{{households}}" id="simple">
    <table>
      <colgroup>
        <col name="$key" sortable/>
      </colgroup>
    </table>
  </vaadin-grid>
```

the data is bound to the grid using a firebase query element.. it works fine(i reduced some attributes from the code)

```
  <firebase-query
    id="query"
    data="{{households}}"
>
```

the problem happens when i try to add buttons just like they did in this[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/NGEosmZvM6lw3dQlQWw0?p=preview)

just for testing i added these three lines of code

```
      var grid = this.$.simple;

      console.log('length '+grid.columns.length);
      console.log(grid.columns);
      console.log(grid.columns[2]);
```

here's the output from these three lines
[image]

as you can see the printed size is 0 but the one displayed at the console is 6(i have no idea why this happens). as far as i know a populated array with 6 elements should look like `Array[6]` instead of `Array[0]` and should be displayed as `[Object, Object .....]` instead of `[]`but i dont quite get what i'm missing here.

Comment: 1) Provide code that shows your problem. 2) You don't access elements of an array using `(index)`. It should be `[index]`.

Comment: How you think with 0 length ? Image says that `length` is 6, and it's seems to be correct

Comment: sorry, i have updated my question with square brackets instead of parenthesis.  the output array  above is from `console.log(grid.columns);`  but i get undefined when i try to use `console.log(grid.columns[2]);`

Comment: But you still didn't post any relevant code.

Comment: what does it print in the dev console when you do `myArr.length`, does it logs `6` or ?

Comment: Take look at this, but I still don't know what is your code structure, so until you put whole code, we can't help you http://jsbin.com/mekiludolo/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I think there is something asynchronous going on there... The `i` with the blue background says "Value below was just evaluated now".

Comment: This is an artifact of how the console displays objects, and what happens when you expand them. There are plenty of questions on the topic here on SO.

Comment: thanks @Redu I did not know what the `i` meant.  i suspect that may be problem. it's weird that the values get updated but the length is not.

Comment: When the array is logged, its empty. Then, it gets updated some time after it was originally logged and before you view it in the console. This is a classic "by reference/by value" question. Google that and learn how it works in javascript. It's the most important thing to understand to master the language

Comment: i just added the code @BelminBedak

Comment: thanks @CharlieMartin i actually understand about asyncronous behaviour. i just had no idea that the  browser console could get updated  assyncrounously(which btw does not happen in the nodeJS console) which seems to be the case here.

Comment: by reference/by value is different than asynchronous but yes you are correct. it can't be updated in node. the browser has some code that redraws the console constantly and any value that is there by reference and has changed will reflect the changes

Comment: Each `console.log()` instruction gets invoked asynchronously so although they are placed one after the other there is no guarantee of consistency here. To guarantee a synchronized manner of log out I would advise yo to do like `console.log('length '+grid.columns.length, grid.columns, grid.columns[2]);`